# Website CSS Formatting Issue in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, wordpress, shopp

I'm working on a Wordpress site and am having trouble getting this page to format properly in IE:

http://piiholozipline.com/shop/

The main content container (#shopp) is pushed down about six inches on the page. This doesn't happen in other browsers, only IE. I've tried various display options (inline) and positioning (absolute, relative, etc.) to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any version of IE appears to be affected.

Comment: Interesting -- when I uncheck any CSS style in the IE8 debugger, the unwanted space disappears. When I re-check the style, it's still gone.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what's going on here. Seems like any fix for IE breaks Firefox and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that when the page loads in IE8, all three images in the slideshow appear at once; then once the jQuery.cycle plugin initializes, the second and third images disappear, leaving the blank space.

This suggests that you can solve the problem by hiding all the images before the DOM loads them. Try adding `display: none;` to `.slide` in your CSS file.

Comment: I think that helped a little bit. Now it's superimposed on top of the slideshow or, if I apply some margin, it'll be to low in Safari/Firefox. Thoughts?

Comment: Try adding `#slide1 { display: block; }` after that.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `overflow:hidden` from `#content` - it's in your ie.css file